# How do I customize a view on a SharePoint list to allow editing by another group after initial data entry by different user?

Tags: infopath, list-view

I have 1 master list that allows users to log information to obtain sequential auto-assigned numbers.  One a quarterly basis the Document Control group will go into the list perform an audit and close out items which have been implemented. I want to designate 3 fields/columns (date closed, record complete? and closed by) of the list specifically for this purpose.

I want 2 views; one for the user requesting the number and another view for Doc Control to modify the record.

How can this be achieved all while using InfoPath Design for my form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

2 lists. One for entry and one for Doc Control. Have the data copied over to a Doc Control list when entered. Doc Control can then modify their list and when they do so, a workflow in the background goes back and updates the original list.